# How to use JQuery to give value to every option of a droplist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The selected option's value can be accessed easily but what about others?

Comment: you need to be more clear about your question, please post related codes , or else it is more likely to get downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#mySelectID option:eq(1)')` to select the 2nd option. From there, do whatever you want.

EDIT: Oops sorry, edited index.

Comment: `eq(2)` will select 3rd  option not 2nd , http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/